# Failure - java.net.SocketTimeoutException: connect timed out while installing plugins in Jenkins

Tags: node.js, jenkins, plugins

I am trying to install NodeJs plugin in my jenkins setup but it is giving me this error

**Failure -
java.net.SocketTimeoutException: connect timed out**

I have also tried to download the plugin manually from  https://updates.jenkins.io/download/plugins/  but still getting the same error.

Any help would be much appreciated!!

Comment: This is a way to general Error code to help you with. Its a connection issue but without more informations about the error probably noone is able to help you. Is there any additional stacktrace you could share?

Comment: Actually it is because http proxy issue due to which plugins are not installing in jenkins setup. Not just NodeJs but it is valid for all the plugins.